# Python Arrow Keys not responding to Paddle

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, pong

Here is my problem that i just can't seem to figure out.

Here is part of my code:

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Paddle:
    def turn_left(self, evt):
            self.y = -3
    def turn_right(self, evt):
            self.y = 3

def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 150, 30, 250, fill = color)
    self.y = 0
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', self.turn_left)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-d>', self.turn_right)


def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
        self.y = 0
    if pos[3] >= f00:
        self.y = 0        

ball = Ball(canvas, 'orange')
paddle = Paddle(canvas, "blue")

while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

and the Paddle doesn't respond to 'a' and 'd' at all.

Now if i take out the 'evt', run the code, and press 'a' or 'd' it gives me an

error, so Python knows I am pressing the keys...

Now what exactly did i do wrong?

Comment: is your indentation really like this?

Comment: Post your *actual* code.  You need both Ball and Paddle classes.  Methods must be indented.

Comment: `if pos[3] >= f00:` f00..? Seems like there is typo in there as well.

Comment: what is `Ball()` ? you didn't add this in code and you don't import it.

Comment: instead of your own loop `while 1` you could use standard loop `root.mailoop()`

Comment: it gives error because `canvas` doesn't exists. Create minimal working example so we could run it.

Comment: name `self.y` is missleading - it should name `self.speed` or `self.move`. In `self.y` you could rather keep positon and then you would no need `pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)`

Comment: on Linux works `<KeyPress-a>` and even `<a>` but I have to keep pressed it, and there is small time before system (Windows/Linux/Mac) starts repeat pressed key and then it moves all the time.

Comment: ha ha okay some mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

In `while` you simply forgot

```
paddle.draw()
```

so keys change `self.y` but it doesn't execute `draw()` which moves paddle.

(and name `self.y` is missleading - it doesn't change paddle position directly)

---

Full working version with other changes (but without ball)

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- classes ---

class Paddle:

    def __init__(self, canvas, color, x, y, key_up, key_down):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

        # if window (and canvas) doesn't exist (yet) then it has size (1,1)
        print('canvas size:', self.canvas_height, self.canvas_width)

        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(x-15, y-50, x+15, y+50, fill=color)

        self.move_y = 0

        self.canvas.bind_all(key_up, self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all(key_down, self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.move_y = -3

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.move_y = 3

    def draw(self):
        if self.move_y != 0:
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[1] <= 0 and self.move_y < 0:
                self.move_y = 0
            if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height and self.move_y > 0:
                self.move_y = 0
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.move_y)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# to create window and canvas 
root.update()

paddle1 = Paddle(canvas, "blue", 15, 150, '<a>', '<d>')
paddle2 = Paddle(canvas, "red", 300-15, 150, '<Up>', '<Down>')

while True:
    paddle1.draw()
    paddle2.draw()
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

[image]